# Configure HP BL460c Gen9 with external iSCSI SAN

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, storage-area-network, iscsi

Hi I am very new to servers. I have a HP BL460c Gen9 server with 650 FLB controller in Legacy mode. I need to connect this to a external SAN through iSCSI.

I am not able to go to the NIC BIOS by pressing "Ctrl+S" to go to the iSCSI settings.

How do I configure the SAN address on the server, so that it boots from SAN?

Comment: I know you *can* boot from iSCSI but do you really need to?

Comment: yes, I hav to boot from SAN over iSCSI

Comment: Interesting question. I almost never hear about boot-from-SAN anymore. Good luck.

Comment: Can you add a USB boot volume to the server? I've seen this in the case that the BIOS was insufficient for the settings required.

Answer (score 1):

The gen9 with 650flb, does support iSCSI boot, but you must use UEFI bios mode. You will then find the settings within the normal bios setup for iSCSI. Assuming you don't use virtual connect(VC), when VC will send down the iSCSI settings.

There is a HP document on it, somewhere on the HP site.

Comment: Can you please share the link for this document.

Comment: http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01861120    HP Boot from SAN Configuration Guide  This outlines it, but you also need to consider how your blades are configured, ie as I mentioned if virtual connect is in use.